# Does there exist a complex polynomial $p$ such that $p(J_k^2(a))=J_k(a)$ if $a\neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Does there exist a complex polynomial $p$ such that $p(J_k^2(a))=J_k(a)$ if $a\neq 0$?
> Here $J_k(a)$ is a $k\times k$ Jordan block whose diagonal element is $a\neq 0$.

What I know is just the Jordan carnonical form of $J_k^2(a)$ is just $J_k(a^2)$.

Comment: The Jordan canonical form of $J_k^2(a)$ is generally $J_k(a^2)$, contrary to what you wrote

Comment: The answer is yes. To show that this is the case, it suffices to show that there exists a polynomial $p_0$ such that $p_0(J_k^2(a)) = J_k(0)$. From there, we can take $p(x) = a + p_0(x)$.

To show that such a $p_0$ exists, start by noting that $J := J_k^2(a) - aI$ is upper-triangular and Toeplitz. From there, one can recursively show that there exist polynomials $q_j(x)$ such that $q_j(J) = J_k(0)^j$ for $j = k-1,k-2,\dots,1$.

Comment: Answered in “[$f$ is a polynomial and $f(0)\neq0$. Why is $fg+x$ a perfect square for some $g$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4579202)” although the question over there has a different setting.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well-known fact that you can calculate the analytic function of a matrix by using the polynomial that interpolates the function and its derivatives at the eigenvalues of the matrix.

If $f$ and $p$ are analytic functions (on a certain domain in $\mathbb{C}$, I do some hand-waving here), $A$ is a matrix, and $\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_m$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity $r_1,\ldots,r_m,$ then
$$
f^{(n)}(\lambda_j)=p^{(n)}(\lambda_j)\;
\forall n\in\{0,\ldots,r_j-1\}\;
\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}
\Longrightarrow f(A) = p(A)
$$
Now set $A=J^2(a)$ and $f(z)=\sqrt{z}.$ Then $m=1,$ $\lambda_1=a^2,$ $f(\lambda_1)=a$ and $r_1=k.$ Then
$$
f^{(n)}(a^2)=p^{(n)}(a^2)\;
\forall n\in\{0,\ldots,k-1\}\;
\Longrightarrow 
p(J^2(a)) = f(J^2(a)) = \sqrt{J^2(a)} = J(a)
$$
(Note that we have to make sure that we use the branch of the square root that yields $a$ for $\sqrt{a^2}$, but not the branch that yields $-a.$ The derivatives must be selected accordingly.)

This shows that we can simply use the Taylor polynomial of degree $k-1$ for the square root, at the point $a^2.$
$$
p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{f^{(n)}\!\left(a^2\right)}{n!}
\left(x-a^2\right)^n
= a+\frac{1}{2a}\left(x-a^2\right)-\frac{1}{8a^3}\left(x-a^2\right)^2+\ldots
$$